# python - from apache_beam.io import fileio gives error: cannot import name fileio

Tags: python, apache, csv

I want to read a csv file into a list in an apache beam application, where each element in the list is a tuple or list (don't really matter), so that I would have the csv

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

become

```
[(1,2,3) , (4,5,6)]
```

or

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
```

I tried following the instructions in [How to convert csv into a dictionary in apache beam dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170997/how-to-convert-csv-into-a-dictionary-in-apache-beam-dataflow)
but when I try to use

```
from beam_utils.sources import CsvFileSource
```

I get

```
from beam_utils.sources import CsvFileSource
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beam_utils/sources.py", line 9, in <module>
    from apache_beam.io import fileio
ImportError: cannot import name fileio
```

If I try to directly import

```
from apache_beam.io import fileio
```

I get the same issue, however I can use both of

```
import apache_beam.io
import beam_utils
```

without any issues. Anyone got a good idea of what the issue might be or got a good idea of how I could do this in a different way?

I currently have

```
with beam.Pipeline(options = pipeline_options) as p:
        csvfile = p | ReadFromText(known_args.input)
```

so if I can turn `csvfile` to the desired format in another way that works well too

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same problem a few minutes ago. The issue is that `fileio` is apparently no longer in `apache_beam` (at least it wasn't for me). It appears to have been replaced by `filesystem`.

Not a great solution, but in sources.py from beam_utils I replaced all instances of "fileio" with "filesystem"

So

```
from apache_beam.io import fileio
```

becomes

```
from apache_beam.io import filesystem
```

Comment: I decided to not use beam_utils in the end and just found a way to input the data into a list/dict myself, but I suspected that something like what you described was the issue. Sometimes ugly fixes are the best :)

Comment: Hi @TrotteBoman, care to share your solution with us? Been looking for this as well. :)

Comment: I suggest these examples https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game @Ventus , if they dont help tell me and I will see if I can be of assistance, but basically all I wrote is from here