# couldn't write data to postgres using apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

i am trying to use Beam to read a csv and send data to postgres.

But the pipeline is failing due to a conversion mismatch. note that this pipeline work when the 2 column are of type int and fail when the type of column contains a string.

here one of the things that i tried.

```
from past.builtins import unicode
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow',[('id',int),('name',unicode)])

beam_df = (pipeline | 'Read CSV' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('path.csv').with_output_types(ExampleRow))
beam_df2 = (convert.to_pcollection(beam_df) | beam.Map(print) |
  WriteToJdbc(
      table_name=table_name,
      jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
      driver_class_name = 'org.postgresql.Driver',
        statement="insert into tablr values(?,?);",
      username=username,
      password=password,
   )
  )
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

I tried also to add an urn to convert the str python type to varchar or unicode but this don't seems to work also

```
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType

@LogicalType.register_logical_type
class db_str(LogicalType):
    @classmethod
    def urn(cls):
        return "beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1"

    @classmethod
    def language_type(cls):
        return unicode

    def to_language_type(self, value):
        return unicode(value)

    def to_representation_type(self, value):
        return unicode(value)
```

ADD: this is the print result :

```
BeamSchema_f0d95d64_95c7_43ba_8a04_ac6a0b7352d9(id=21, nom='nom21')
BeamSchema_f0d95d64_95c7_43ba_8a04_ac6a0b7352d9(id=22, nom='nom22')
BeamSchema_f0d95d64_95c7_43ba_8a04_ac6a0b7352d9(id=21, nom='nom21')
BeamSchema_f0d95d64_95c7_43ba_8a04_ac6a0b7352d9(id=22, nom='nom22')
```

the problem comes from the WriteToJdbc function and the 'nom' column.

any idea how to make this work ?

Comment: Can you share the result  of your `print` function : the result `PCollection` containing `String` columns and which causes the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is due to you have `BeamSchema` structure instead of expected `NamedTuple` in your output `PCollection`.

Also, according to the documentation, a code instruction is missing in your example `coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)` :

[apache_beam_io_jdbc doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html)

```py
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow',
                               [('id', int), ('name', unicode)])
coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)

with TestPipeline() as p:
  _ = (
      p
      | beam.Create([ExampleRow(1, 'abc')])
          .with_output_types(ExampleRow)
      | 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
          driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
          jdbc_url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example',
          username='postgres',
          password='postgres',
          statement='INSERT INTO example_table VALUES(?, ?)',
      ))
```

The following code in your snippet, doesn't set `ExampleRow` `NamedTuple` as expected, because your `print` indicates the type is `BeamSchema` :

```py
beam_df = (pipeline | 'Read CSV' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('path.csv').with_output_types(ExampleRow))
```

Try with this code before :

```py
from past.builtins import unicode
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow',[('id',int),('name',unicode)])

# Register coder here
coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)

beam_df = (pipeline | 'Read CSV' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('path.csv').with_output_types(ExampleRow))
```

If it doesn't works, you need to find a way to transform your `BeamSchema` to `ExampleRow` `NamedTuple` in a `DoFn` :

```py
def convert_beam_schema_to_named_tuple(beam_schema) -> ExampleRow :
   # Your logic to transform Beam Schema to ExampleRow NamedTuple

from past.builtins import unicode
ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow',[('id',int),('name',unicode)])

beam_df = (pipeline | 'Read CSV' >> beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('path.csv').with_output_types(ExampleRow))
beam_df2 = (convert.to_pcollection(beam_df) 
            | beam.Map(print) 
            | beam.Map(convert_beam_schema_to_named_tuple) 

            | WriteToJdbc(
               table_name=table_name,
               jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
               driver_class_name = 'org.postgresql.Driver',
               statement="insert into tablr values(?,?);",
               username=username,
               password=password,
   )
  )
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

At the end, if you have issue with Beam schema and Beam dataframe, you can read the `CSV` file directly with `Beam` `IO` and work with `PCollection`

You can check this link : [csv-into-a-dictionary-in-apache-beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170997/how-to-convert-csv-into-a-dictionary-in-apache-beam-dataflow)

Comment: thank you, yes it seems that i need to convert the PCollection again after the conversion and adding the `beam.Map(lambda x: x).with_output_types(ExampleRow) ` did the work.